# Can't remove Rows from existing csv file in AWS S3 using python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, amazon-s3, boto3

Unable to remove Rows from existing csv file in AWS S3 using python,
Currently, I was able to read write and append data using my code, but when i try to drop a row, i got the following error

**MY CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import csv
Name = "database-2"
Launch_time = "2021-07-09T11:04:80z"
Region = "us-east-2"
data_list = {'Instance_name': [Name],
            'Created_time ':  [Launch_time],
            'Region       ':  [Region]}
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
bytes_to_write = df.to_csv(None, header=None, index=False).encode()
print(bytes_to_write)
file_name = 'blank.csv'
# get the existing file
current_data = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='test-lambda', Key=file_name)['Body'].read()
# append
print(current_data)
appended_data = current_data + bytes_to_write
# drop raw 2
appended_data = appended_data.drop([2], axis=0)
# overwrite
s3_client.put_object(Body=appended_data, Bucket='test-lambda', Key=file_name)
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 21, in <module>
    appended_data = appended_data.drop([2], axis=0)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'drop'
```

how to resolve this? please help me...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a line where you read the raw csv data back into a pandas dataframe object.  Something like:

```
df.from_csv.......
```

Currently you're concatenating raw bytes then running a drop command on it which is why you're getting the error.